# What are the integers that lack unique factorization in $\mathbb Z[\zeta_n],$ $n= 23$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, prime-factorization, unique-factorization-domains, cyclotomic-fields

In the cyclotomic integers $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$, $n=23$ has class number $3$ and so unique factorization fails (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_field ). Can anyone give me examples of such integers that have more than one ($3$?) prime factorizations?  Is there a formula to calculate them?  Do some or most or all integers have this property?  Thanks.

Comment: Take a prime $p$ that splits completely as a product of 22 non-principal ideals $P_j$, we can order them such that $P_1\ldots P_5$ are all in the same class of order $3$. Then $p=ab=cd$ where $(a)=P_1P_2P_3,(c)=P_1P_4P_5$ are both irreducible.